# Convert HTML to Image in React Native

Tags: html, react-native, png

I'm currently trying to generate an image (png/jpg) from an html string in React Native such as follows:

```
<table><tr><th>Company</th><th>Contact</th><th>Country</th></tr><tr><td>AlfredsFutterkiste</td>" +
        "<td>MariaAnders</td><td>Germany</td></tr><tr><td>CentrocomercialMoctezuma</td><td>FranciscoChang</td>" +
        "<td>Mexico</td></tr><tr><td>ErnstHandel</td><td>RolandMendel</td><td>Austria</td></tr><tr>" +
        "<td>IslandTrading</td><td>HelenBennett</td><td>UK</td></tr></table>
```

I found some good third party implementations that generates pdfs from html strings (https://github.com/christopherdro/react-native-html-to-pdf) but none for generating images from html.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 node packages that can help you with converting a given DOM to an svg/png/jpeg image:

https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image

https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-image